# Какое отличие состояния от характеристики в Java?

Tags: java, терминология

Какое отличие состояния от характеристики в Java?

Класс - некая абстракция, логическая структура, описывающая поведение и характеристики.

> Разве описывающая поведение и характеристики, разве не состояние?

**Какое вообще отличие характеристики от состояния?**

Comment: характеристика это свойство, а состояние - конкретное значение этого свойства. например характеристика - скорость, состояние = 10м/с

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Спасибо большое! Напишите в ответ я приму.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а как правильней формально характеристика или свойство? Просто свойство я слышал, а про характеристику недавно увидел

Comment: я думаю Вас поймут если скажете и то и то

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Характеристика это свойство, а состояние - конкретное значение этого свойства.

Примеры:

```
характеристика - состояние 
-----------------------------
 скорость(м/с) -    10
     цвет      -  зеленый
    масса(г)   -    13
 угол(радиан   -    0.5
```